# Upload file and save it with original name in storage folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I want to save uploaded file with the original name. For exampple, when I upload **web.jpg** the filename in my storage folder should be **web.jpg** too.

I already tried many methods and I still don't know how to solve this problem.

**My productController**

```php
 public function store(Request $request)
 {
    if($request->hasFile('image'))
    {
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $originalname = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $filename =$originalname;
        $file->move('public/', $filename);
    }


    product::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'id_kategori' => $request->kategori,
        'quantity' => $request->quantity,
        'price' => $request->price, 
        'slug' => $request->slug,
        'image' =>  'public/'. $filename,
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('produk.index');
}
```

**My Index.Blade.php**

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>No</th>
                    <th>Nama</th>
                    <th>Kategori</th>
                    <th>Stok Barang</th>
                    <th>Harga Barang</th>
                    <th>Foto</th>
                    <th>Dibuat Pada</th>
                    <th>Diedit Pada</th>
                    <th colspan="8" style="text-align:center;">Aksi</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach ($products as $i => $products)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $i+1 }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $products->name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $products->Kategori->name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $products->quantity }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $products->price }}</td>
                        <td><img src="{{\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::url($products->image)}}"></td>
                        <td>{{ $products->created_at }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $products->updated_at }}</td>
                        <td><a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('produk.edit',$products->id) }}"> Edit</a></td>
                        <td>
                              <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route('show',$products->name) }}"> Lihat</a>
                        <td>
                            <form method="post" action="{{ route('produk.destroy',$products->id) }}">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
                                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Hapus</button>
                            </form>
                        </td>    
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <a href="{{ route('produk.create') }}" class="btn btn-primary">Tambah Produk</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the extension to the file, so try this:

```
$picture = $file->getClientOriginalName() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
$file->move(public_path(), $picture);
```

Comment: it's not what i mean, i want to save file that has been uploaded in storage folder with original name, so when i upload file like web.jpg i get web.jpg in my storage folder.My problem's when i upload web.jpg i get b7fVASZ4e5atIFhHlNPIc9DOpsa3bpcltMhcvnkO.jpeg in my storage folder

Comment: This is the code that I am using in my project and it works perfectly fine, uploading web.jpg saves web.jpg into the public directory. Your name seems like you do a md5. Try to look at the documentation of the `UploadFile` class `getClientOriginalName()` and you will see that it returns what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can try file_put_contents() to store the file.

file_put_contents('/path/to/storege, file_get_contents('http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=400x400&cht=qr&chl=Test'));

Answer (score 0):

I know we're  all here to learn from others. I will even recommend to change your code little bit for flexibility. Let try the codes below.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{   //let validate the image format;
  $this->validate($request,['image'=> 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,bmp,png',];

$file = $request->file('image'); // let request the file first
if (isset($file))
{
    $originalname = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $file_extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $filename = $originalname.'.'.$file_extension;

  //Now let set the path where the image will be saved.
   if (!file_exists('upload/Images')) // if this path doesn't exist
      {
        mkdir(''upload/Images', 0777 , true); // create the path
      }
      $file->move(''upload/Images',$file_name); // save the file to this path
      }else{ //optional
       $file_name = 'NoFile.jpg'; // I always set a default image that can be used if the user doesn't have an photo
      }

product::create([
    'name' => $request->name,
    'id_kategori' => $request->kategori,
    'quantity' => $request->quantity,
    'price' => $request->price, 
    'slug' => $request->slug,
    'image' => $filename,
]);

return redirect()->route('produk.index');
}

// In your index.blade.view
// To be able to display the image in your view, use the code below:
   <td>
     <img src="{{ asset('upload/Images/'.$products->image) }}" >
   </td>  

DO NOT FORGET to include enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form like below:
<form class="form-control" method="POST" action=" 
{{route('your_route')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```